# Hardbirck phone showing as unknow device instead MediaTek device

Tags: custom-roms, mediatek

My phone (Redmi 9A) is in a hard brick state after an unsuccessful attempt to flash a custom ROM. Unfortunately, when I connect it to my computer (running Windows 11), it appears as an "unknown device" instead of a "MediaTek" device. Please advise on how to make my computer recognize the phone as a MediaTek device.

Important information :

The device was recognized as mediatek. It only stopped when I stopped the repair process. The tool I tried to repair the phone was smartphone flash tool